# Infinispan and JGroups discovery on EC2

Tags: spring, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, infinispan, jgroups

I'm trying to use my application on AWS EC2 on some Linux boxes with Tomcat servers. Previously I used my application with Infinispan on LAN and I used UDP multicasting for JGroups member discovery. EC2 does not support UDP multicasting and this is the default node discovery approach used by Infinispan to detect nodes running in a cluster. I looked into using the S3_PING protocol, but I have not figured out why it doesn't work.

Does anyone have any ideas what the problem might be here?

Here is my configuration files: 
1. applicationContext-cache.xml

```
<!-- Infinispan cache -->
<cache:annotation-driven/>

<import resource="classpath:/applicationContext-dao.xml"/>


<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.infinispan.spring.provider.SpringEmbeddedCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="configurationFileLocation" value="classpath:/infinispan-replication.xml"/>
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.alex.cache"/>
```

2.infinispan-replication.xml

```
<infinispan xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:5.1 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-5.1.xsd"
        xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:5.1">

<global>
    <transport transportClass="org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport">
        <properties>
            <property name="configurationFile" value="/home/akasiyanik/dev/projects/myapp/myapp-configs/jgroups.xml"/>
        </properties>
    </transport>
</global>

<default>
    <!-- Configure a synchronous replication cache -->
    <clustering mode="replication">
        <sync/>
        <hash numOwners="2"/>
    </clustering>
</default>
</infinispan>
```

3. jgroups.xml

```
<config>
    <TCP bind_port="${jgroups.tcp.port:7800}"
      loopback="true"
      port_range="30"
      recv_buf_size="20000000"
      send_buf_size="640000"
      discard_incompatible_packets="true"
      max_bundle_size="64000"
      max_bundle_timeout="30"        
      enable_bundling="true"
      use_send_queues="true"
      sock_conn_timeout="300"
      enable_diagnostics="false"
      thread_pool.enabled="true"
      thread_pool.min_threads="2"
      thread_pool.max_threads="30"
      thread_pool.keep_alive_time="60000"
      thread_pool.queue_enabled="false"
      thread_pool.queue_max_size="100"
      thread_pool.rejection_policy="Discard"

      oob_thread_pool.enabled="true"
      oob_thread_pool.min_threads="2"
      oob_thread_pool.max_threads="30"
      oob_thread_pool.keep_alive_time="60000"
      oob_thread_pool.queue_enabled="false"
      oob_thread_pool.queue_max_size="100"
      oob_thread_pool.rejection_policy="Discard"
     />
    <S3_PING location="r********s" access_key="AK***************SIA"
      secret_access_key="y*************************************BJ" timeout="2000" num_initial_members="2"/>
    <MERGE2 max_interval="30000"
        min_interval="10000"/>
    <FD_SOCK/>
    <FD timeout="3000" max_tries="3"/>
    <VERIFY_SUSPECT timeout="1500"/>
    <BARRIER />
    <pbcast.NAKACK use_mcast_xmit="false"
               exponential_backoff="500"
               discard_delivered_msgs="true"/>
    <UNICAST />
    <pbcast.STABLE stability_delay="1000" desired_avg_gossip="50000"
               max_bytes="4M"/>
    <pbcast.GMS print_local_addr="true" join_timeout="3000" 
            view_bundling="true"/>
    <UFC max_credits="2M"
     min_threshold="0.4"/>
    <MFC max_credits="2M"
     min_threshold="0.4"/>
   <FRAG2 frag_size="60K" />
   <pbcast.STATE_TRANSFER/>
</config>
```

Comment: Hard to say really... assuming the problem you have is that nodes don't join, I'd enable TRACE logging on org.jgroups package and see what's going. Config looks fine at first glance...

Comment: @GalderZamarreño Thanks for advice. But all that I need to do is use IPv4 instead IPv6. For that I used specified JVM arguments to prefer IPv4: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses=true.

Answer (score 2):

Use this: https://github.com/meltmedia/jgroups-aws

It is an implementation of JGroups discovery protocol for AWS using AWS API (multicast replacement)